# How to block a rebase --skip if I have staged changes?

Tags: git, rebase, githooks

Git already blocks a `--continue` if you have unstaged changes. It makes sense to block `--skip` if you have staged changes. Is there a git hook I can modify to block rebase --skip in a similar way?

Comment: I can't find a `git merge --skip`. What do you mean?

Comment: You can have conflicts in a merge or a rebase, and you get instructed to either abort, continue or skip.

Comment: But the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) state `git merge (--continue | --abort | --quit)` - `quit`, not `skip`?

Comment: Ahh I assumed that merge had all the same values as rebase